# Problem loading ubuntu

Tags: kernel

I bought a used laptop with the hard drive wiped clean. Tried to load 14.04 got a message that kernel has to be loaded first. Reloaded xp and tried again, same thing?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt download.

Comment: Did you use an USB or DVD? How did you create it? Did you xompare the ISO's MD5 hash with the one given at the download site?

Answer (score 0):

- Download the fresh ISO from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ and then try again.